# Tkinter - Moving the dots on a polyline with three path

Tags: python, tkinter, polyline

Based on a simple Line drawn using `canvas.create_line`, such as this [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL01n.png), three dots, based on the start, middle, and end of the line are created, [example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sNAI.png).

I want to be able to click and drag the part of the Line where there is a dot, so I made the following MRE:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

line = canvas.create_line(50, 50, 350, 50, width=3)

start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y = canvas.coords(line)

start_dot = canvas.create_oval(start_x - 5, start_y - 5, start_x + 5, start_y + 5, fill='blue', tags=('start_dot',))
end_dot = canvas.create_oval(end_x - 5, end_y - 5, end_x + 5, end_y + 5, fill='red', tags=('end_dot',))

mid_x = (start_x + end_x) / 2
mid_y = start_y

mid_dot = canvas.create_oval(mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5, fill='green', tags=('mid_dot',))


def update_line(event):
    global end_x, end_y, start_y, start_x, mid_y, mid_x, curve
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    item = canvas.find_withtag(tk.CURRENT)[0]
    if item == start_dot:
        canvas.coords(start_dot, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5)
        canvas.coords(line, x, y, end_x, end_y)
    elif item == end_dot:
        canvas.coords(end_dot, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5)
        canvas.coords(line, start_x, start_y, x, y)
    elif item == mid_dot:
        dx = x - (start_x + end_x) // 2
        dy = y - (start_y + end_y) // 2
        canvas.coords(mid_dot, mid_x + dx - 5, mid_y + dy - 5, mid_x + dx + 5, mid_y + dy + 5)
        canvas.coords(line, start_x, start_y, mid_x + dx, mid_y + dy, end_x, end_y)
    else:
        return

    test = canvas.coords(line)
    if len(test) == 4:
        start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, = canvas.coords(line)
        mid_x = (start_x + end_x) / 2
        mid_y = (start_y + end_y) / 2
        canvas.coords(mid_dot, mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5)
    else:
        pass


canvas.tag_bind('start_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)
canvas.tag_bind('end_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)
canvas.tag_bind('mid_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)

root.mainloop()
```

This somewhat works, at least for only moving the start and end correctly. The part that doesn't work yet is updating the Line correctly after moving the middle dot and then moving either the start or end dot of the Line.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUfty.jpg) is a gif showcasing the problem, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD9tB.jpg) the expected behavior (the rectangle can be ignored).

I noticed `canvas.coords` output 5 values instead of the usual 4 that I'm used to.

How can I make the above works with the middle path/dot too?

P.S.:I use the term "polyline" but I'm not sure if this is what I'm actually doing here (it does look similar when looking on google image). Feel free to mention a better fitting term for this if there is one.

Comment: Your life will be *so* much easier if you draw the line with three points always - rather than having to special-case having two or three points based on whether the middle point had ever been moved (which is what it would take to fix your current approach).

Comment: I mostly did it like this because I wanted to extend this by removing/hiding the dots, and putting them back whenever a mouse click happen on the line. But you're right, this would be easier...feel free to post a solution if possible @jasonharper

Comment: You could give the dots tags to what item they are related and have an additional tag on each dot to what index coordinate they belong to, then you just have to manipulate the coordinate with the index of N.

Comment: That's a good idea, yeah. I did make a version that used tags, but didn't think of using them for the index too @Thingamabobs

Comment: Btw, don't know if you saw the answer I made, but I credited you. Feel free to comment about it if you want too, cheers. @jasonharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [jasonharper's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75963117/tkinter-moving-the-dots-on-a-polyline-with-three-path#comment133980798_75963117) comment, I managed to find a way to solve this:

> Your life will be so much easier if you draw the line with three points always - rather than having to special-case having two or three points based on whether the middle point had ever been moved (which is what it would take to fix your current approach). –
> jasonharper
> Apr 8 at 3:11

First a solution that does not directly follow the wanted behavior (works for all three path/dot, but does not move the entire line when using only start and end dot):

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

line = canvas.create_line(50, 50, 350, 50, width=3)

start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y = canvas.coords(line)

start_dot = canvas.create_oval(start_x - 5, start_y - 5, start_x + 5, start_y + 5, fill='blue', tags=('start_dot',))
end_dot = canvas.create_oval(end_x - 5, end_y - 5, end_x + 5, end_y + 5, fill='red', tags=('end_dot',))

mid_x = (start_x + end_x) / 2
mid_y = start_y

mid_dot = canvas.create_oval(mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5, fill='green', tags=('mid_dot',))

def update_line(event):
    global start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, mid_x, mid_y

    x, y = event.x, event.y
    item = canvas.find_withtag(tk.CURRENT)[0]

    if item == start_dot:
        start_x, start_y = x, y
    elif item == end_dot:
        end_x, end_y = x, y
    elif item == mid_dot:
        mid_x, mid_y = x, y

    canvas.coords(line, start_x, start_y, mid_x, mid_y, end_x, end_y)

    canvas.coords(start_dot, start_x - 5, start_y - 5, start_x + 5, start_y + 5)
    canvas.coords(end_dot, end_x - 5, end_y - 5, end_x + 5, end_y + 5)
    canvas.coords(mid_dot, mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5)

canvas.tag_bind('start_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)
canvas.tag_bind('end_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)
canvas.tag_bind('mid_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)

root.mainloop()
```

And now, a solution that both move the entire line at first (only using start and end dots), and then move it partially after the middle dot have been used at least once:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

line = canvas.create_line(50, 50, 350, 50, width=3)

start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y = canvas.coords(line)

start_dot = canvas.create_oval(start_x - 5, start_y - 5, start_x + 5, start_y + 5, fill='blue', tags=('start_dot',))
end_dot = canvas.create_oval(end_x - 5, end_y - 5, end_x + 5, end_y + 5, fill='red', tags=('end_dot',))

mid_x = (start_x + end_x) / 2
mid_y = start_y

mid_dot = canvas.create_oval(mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5, fill='green', tags=('mid_dot',))
has_middle_dot_moved = False


def update_line(event):
    global end_x, end_y, start_y, start_x, mid_y, mid_x, has_middle_dot_moved
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    item = canvas.find_withtag(tk.CURRENT)[0]
    if not has_middle_dot_moved:
        if item == start_dot:
            canvas.coords(start_dot, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5)
            canvas.coords(line, x, y, end_x, end_y)
        elif item == end_dot:
            canvas.coords(end_dot, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5)
            canvas.coords(line, start_x, start_y, x, y)
        elif item == mid_dot:
            has_middle_dot_moved = True
        start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, = canvas.coords(line)
        mid_x = (start_x + end_x) / 2
        mid_y = (start_y + end_y) / 2
        canvas.coords(mid_dot, mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5)
    else:
        if item == start_dot:
            start_x, start_y = x, y
        elif item == end_dot:
            end_x, end_y = x, y
        elif item == mid_dot:
            mid_x, mid_y = x, y

        canvas.coords(line, start_x, start_y, mid_x, mid_y, end_x, end_y)

        canvas.coords(start_dot, start_x - 5, start_y - 5, start_x + 5, start_y + 5)
        canvas.coords(end_dot, end_x - 5, end_y - 5, end_x + 5, end_y + 5)
        canvas.coords(mid_dot, mid_x - 5, mid_y - 5, mid_x + 5, mid_y + 5)


canvas.tag_bind('start_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)
canvas.tag_bind('end_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)
canvas.tag_bind('mid_dot', '<B1-Motion>', update_line)

root.mainloop()
```